# Не работают методы для TextView

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

В моей прораммме есть AsyncTask, в котором выполняются некоторые вычисления данных для TextView. В методе onPostExecute() я устанавливаю нужный текст в TextView и пытаюсь системно проскролить TextView методом scrollBy(); Но проблема в том, что с TextView ничего не происходит и это странно, потому что все данные, которые передаются в scrollBy() не нулевые. В чем может быть проблема?

onPostExec:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        pd.hide();

        String s = currentText.toString();
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
        currentText = new StringBuilder(Html.fromHtml(s));

        //Подсчет страниц(сразу при запуске, как ты и просил)
        countOfLines = (textView.getHeight() / textView.getLineHeight());
        pages = Math.round(textView.getLineCount() / countOfLines) + 1;
        pagesView.setText(currentPage + "/" + pages);

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Toast.makeText(readerActivity, Long.toString(end - start) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        scroll();
    }
```

scroll():

```
void scroll(){
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        textView.scrollBy(0, 1000);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Заменил строку

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

на строку

```
textView.append(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

и все заработало, только все равно не могу понять в чем проблема с setText(). Он ведь вызывается перед scroll()

Comment: Если вы самостоятельно нашли решение проблемы, нужно оформить его в виде ответа (ответить на собственный вопрос), а не писать его в вопросе.

Comment: Решение проблемы я нашел, но не ответ на главный вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

метод `scroll()` попробуйте посадить в `View.post()`:

```
textView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scroll();
            }
        });
```

Смысл в том, что `scroll()` должен отработать после отрисовки UI.